# Multiple instances of JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a small plugin. I want to be able to use this plugin on multiple elements on the same page, but with different options.

When I click on one of these elements, let's call it element A, I want the plugin to do stuff to that element (A). But as it is now, instead it does stuff to element B, no matter which element I click on.

For example:

```
$(".elementA").myplugin({"name": "Element A"});    
$(".elementB").myplugin({"name": "Element B"});

(function($) {
$.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
    return new Myplugin (this, options);
}

var Myplugin = function (element, options) {
    this.element = $(element);
    this.settings = $.extend({
        "name": "default"
    });

    var self = this;
    this.element.on("click", function(e) {
        self.doStuff(e);
    });
};

Myplugin.prototype = {
    doStuff: function (e) {
        console.log(this.settings.name) // returns element B, no matter which element I click on.
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

It seems that when I add the plugin to the Element B, the "this" in the doStuff function points to element B, in every instance of the plugin. What is it that I'm not understanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

It seems that I forget the "var" before self = this, and instead declared a global variable in the original code (I did though subconsciously write it correctly above).